# Rotated squares as an Image

Tags: html, css

I'm new in HTML, CSS. Also I'm still learn so please be understanding.

I'm trying to do some kind of art gallery which will be looks like this:

[image]

I create this squares with help of tutorial, but I want to upgrade thisand put an image instead squares, but I have no idea how to do this. Any tips ?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #99CCFF;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1070px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.diamond {
  width: 11.5%;
  padding-bottom: 11.5%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  display: inline-block;
}
.diamond-big {
  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  display: inline-block;
}
.grid {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 39%;
}
.grid-section {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}
#diamond1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 10.5%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#diamond2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 24%;
}
#diamond3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11.5%;
  left: 37.5%;
}
#diamond4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 24%;
}
#diamond5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 51%;
}
#diamond6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 52%;
  left: 51%;
}
#diamond7 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 64.5%;
}
#diamond8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65.5%;
  left: 51%;
}
#diamond9 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65.5%;
  left: 64.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="grid-section">
    <div class="grid">
      <div id="diamond1" class="diamond"></div>
      <div id="diamond2" class="diamond"></div>
      <div id="diamond3" class="diamond-big"></div>
      <div id="diamond4" class="diamond-big"></div>
      <div id="diamond5" class="diamond"></div>
      <div id="diamond6" class="diamond"></div>
      <div id="diamond7" class="diamond-big"></div>
      <div id="diamond8" class="diamond"></div>
      <div id="diamond9" class="diamond-big"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: you could add background image to the divs

Comment: Use transform: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Please clarify in your question, per comments below, that you would like the images inside the diamonds to not be rotated also.

Comment: I forget to add that I want to images won't be rotated as the squares. I want images to be like diamonds.

Comment: @T.Reguła I've updated my answer so the images won't be rotated.

Comment: @RobinB Thanks you Very much! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the images easy downloadable or don't want to use background-image in css, you can do something like this. I've added images inside the divs and added the following css:

```
.diamond {
  width: 11.5%;
  padding-bottom: 11.5%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
 }

 .diamond img, .diamond-big img 
 { position:absolute;
   left:-25%;
  top:-25%;
   width:150%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }

.diamond-big {
  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
```

this makes the images as large as the squares.

Full code snippet:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #99CCFF;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1070px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.diamond {
  width: 11.5%;
  padding-bottom: 11.5%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
 }

.diamond img, .diamond-big img 
{ position:absolute;
  left:-25%;
 top:-25%;
  width:150%;
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.diamond-big {
  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.grid {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 39%;
}
.grid-section {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}
#diamond1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 10.5%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#diamond2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 24%;
}
#diamond3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11.5%;
  left: 37.5%;
}
#diamond4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 24%;
}
#diamond5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 51%;
}
#diamond6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 52%;
  left: 51%;
}
#diamond7 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 64.5%;
}
#diamond8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65.5%;
  left: 51%;
}
#diamond9 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65.5%;
  left: 64.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="grid-section">
    <div class="grid">
      <div id="diamond1" class="diamond"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="alter"/></div>

      <div id="diamond2" class="diamond"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="alter"/></div>

      <div id="diamond3" class="diamond-big"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="alter"/></div>

      <div id="diamond4" class="diamond-big"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="alter"/></div>

      <div id="diamond5" class="diamond"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="alter"/></div>

      <div id="diamond6" class="diamond"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="alter"/></div>

      <div id="diamond7" class="diamond-big"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="alter"/></div>

      <div id="diamond8" class="diamond"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="alter"/></div>

      <div id="diamond9" class="diamond-big"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="alter"/></div>

    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: OP would like images to not be rotated 45 degrees.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the property background-image to the **diamond** and **diamond-big** classes. For example:

```
.diamond {
    width: 11.5%;
    padding-bottom: 11.5%;
    background-image: url("image.jpg");
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you don't see the image anyway, try to add **height** property too.

Comment: Can I rotate 
`background-image`?

Answer (score 0):

There are **many ways to do this**

One of the **quickest** is to **swap out** the `<div>` tags with `<img>` tags while keeping the `class` and `id` attributes

*in your case you need to adjust some of you CSS to avoid unnecessary padding*

here's a working example: (needs polishing)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #99CCFF;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1070px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.diamond {
  width: 11.5%;
  padding: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  display: inline-block;
}
.diamond-big {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  display: inline-block;
}
.grid {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 39%;
}
.grid-section {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}
#diamond1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 10.5%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#diamond2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 24%;
}
#diamond3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11.5%;
  left: 37.5%;
}
#diamond4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 24%;
}
#diamond5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 51%;
}
#diamond6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 52%;
  left: 51%;
}
#diamond7 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 64.5%;
}
#diamond8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65.5%;
  left: 51%;
}
#diamond9 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65.5%;
  left: 64.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Pokręcone Gridy</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/alert.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <section class="grid-section">
      <div class="grid">
        <img id="diamond1" src="http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large-5/blink-cat-square-art-michelle-wrighton.jpg" class="diamond">
        <img id="diamond2" src="http://vastrevets.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Cat-square-1-300x258.jpg" class="diamond">
        <img id="diamond3" src="http://www.summitmobilevet.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/cat-square.jpg" class="diamond-big">
        <img id="diamond4" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-gMWmYwKZYZk/TvZFNMxEE0I/AAAAAAAAB1Q/Ka6cF95MCVA/s1600/mousecattoy1square.jpg" class="diamond-big">
        <img id="diamond5" src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB13WWmIpXXXXbEXpXXq6xXFXXXy/DIY-Diamond-embroidery-font-b-Small-b-font-font-b-cat-b-font-square-drill-paste.jpg" class="diamond">
        <img id="diamond6" src="http://fineartamerica.com/images/artworkimages/medium/1/orange-tabby-cat--square-jai-johnson.jpg" class="diamond">
        <img id="diamond7" src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1C339KVXXXXaGXpXXq6xXFXXX8/Needlework-Diamond-Embroidery-Home-Decoration-Diamond-Painting-Cross-Stitch-font-b-Laughing-b-font-Cat-Square.jpg" class="diamond-big">
        <img id="diamond8" src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1UsFCKpXXXXXPXXXXq6xXFXXXh/Diamond-embroidery-Three-font-b-small-b-font-font-b-cats-b-font-square-drill-paste.jpg" class="diamond">
        <img id="diamond9" src="http://www.dhresource.com/0x0s/f2-albu-g1-M00-CD-F9-rBVaGVVN8-mAa_kSAACnesiYQsA716.jpg/diy-square-diamond-painting-cat-cartoon-animal.jpg" class="diamond-big">
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP would like images to not be rotated 45 degrees.

Comment: Thank you @hungerstar. I actually don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have two options:

Option 1: HTML and CSS (max-width)
You can just simply insert the img inside your div and set the max-width to 100%, like:

```
<div id="diamond2" class="diamond">
<img style="max-width: 100%" src="yourpicture.jpg">
</div>
```

If you do this, you have to make sure the divs are set to the right size for the picture (or at least the proportions), and use the max-width attribute.

Option 2: Using CSS
Set them as background on your CSS and use the right type of background-size (cover or contain):

```
    #diamond6 {
           background-image: url('yourpicture.jpg'); 
           background-size: cover;
           position: absolute;
           top: 52%; 
           left: 51%;
          }
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use background-image with background-size like

```
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #99CCFF;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1070px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.diamond {
  width: 11.5%;
  padding-bottom: 11.5%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.diamond-big {
  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  display: inline-block;
}
.grid {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 39%;
}
.grid-section {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}
#diamond1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 10.5%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#diamond2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 24%;
}
#diamond3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11.5%;
  left: 37.5%;
}
#diamond4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 24%;
}
#diamond5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 51%;
}
#diamond6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 52%;
  left: 51%;
}
#diamond7 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38.5%;
  left: 64.5%;
}
#diamond8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65.5%;
  left: 51%;
}
#diamond9 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65.5%;
  left: 64.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="grid-section">
    <div class="grid">
      <div id="diamond1" class="diamond"></div>
      <div id="diamond2" class="diamond"></div>
      <div id="diamond3" class="diamond-big"></div>
      <div id="diamond4" class="diamond-big"></div>
      <div id="diamond5" class="diamond"></div>
      <div id="diamond6" class="diamond"></div>
      <div id="diamond7" class="diamond-big"></div>
      <div id="diamond8" class="diamond"></div>
      <div id="diamond9" class="diamond-big"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```